# $location.path() not working correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this code changing path when user not authorized, but view update only after page reload.
$state.reload() and $rootScope.apply() don't help.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  if (!$localStorage.authenticate) {
        $rootScope.authenticate = false;

     if (next.url == '/reset_password/:token') {
          console.log('reset password page');
        }
        else if (next.url == '/forgot_password') {
          $location.path(next.url);

        }
        else {
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      }
      else {
        $rootScope.authenticate = true;
        if ((next.url == '/login') || (next.url == '/forgot') || (next.url == '/reset_password/:token')) {
          $location.path('/index');


        }
        $rootScope.userName = $localStorage.userName;
        API.getService('/login').get(function (res) {
          if (!res.logged) {
            $location.path('/login');
            delete $localStorage.userName;
            $localStorage.authenticate = false;
          }
        })
      }
    });
```

Comment: $state ? That mean you are using ui-router ?

Comment: yes, i'm use ui-router

Comment: can you add your app.js which has $routeProvider?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EaaSsFqT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ui router you should not use `$location`

To change state you have to use this :

```
 $state.go("mystatename", {urlParam:value});
```

In your HTML don't use href, use ui-sref instead :

```
 ui-sref = "mystatename({urlParam:value})"
```

Hope it solved your issue.

Comment: error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: On which line ? Could you provide it ?

Comment: @user2304181 I got it. When you use $state.go() to redirect it fire a $stateChangeStart ... And this event will redirect... again and again. You need to add a if "next" = "yourloginstate". Then it should be fine.

Comment: something wrong,          

 console.log(next.url);
          if (next.url !== '/login') {
            $state.go("login");
          }

in console : 
/main
/login

but view still not login

Comment: SOLVED: i'm use $locationChangeSuccess event